# Console destroy the Output screen

Tags: bug, stack-snippets-console

When something is logged in console, the scroll bar is not adjust automatically and hide the bottom of the Output screen.

[image]
In the above image, I added a click Event Listener to the button to console some text.

When I click that button

[image]

The scrollbar is not adjusting and so, the bottom is not visible.

[tested on Edge and Chrome on windows 10 x64]

I am adding the sample below

```js
function add(){
  console.log("test\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest");
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Try running it and click the button